# Sympy and lambda functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I want to generate a list of basic monomial from x^0 to x^n (in particular, n=9) using Sympy. My quick solution is a simple list comprehension combined with Python's lambda function syntax:

```
import sympy as sym
x = sym.symbols('x')

monomials = [lambda x: x**n for n in range(10)]
```

However, when I verify that `monomials` is constructed as expected, I find that:

```
print([f(x) for f in monomials])
>>> [x**9, x**9, x**9, x**9, x**9, x**9, x**9, x**9, x**9, x**9]
```

If I redefine `monomials` without using the lambda syntax, I get what I would otherwise expect:

```
monomials = [x**n for n in range(10)]
print(monomials)
>>> [1, x, x**2, x**3, x**4, x**5, x**6, x**7, x**8, x**9]
```

Why do I get this behavior?

---

**Specs**:

- Python 3.5.1
- Sympy 1.0

I am using the Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit) package manager.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use second arg with default value

```
monomials = [lambda x, n=n: x**n for n in range(10)]
```

otherwise you have a closure and get not value but reference to `n`.